# User roles and claim are not recognized when using Asp.Net Core Identity with External login provider

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

In my system I'm using AzureAD as external login to authenticate users in my organization. When I created the App I choose the the authentication type as Microsoft external authentication. I connected my app to the app registered in AzureAD

I got this code in my program.cs file

```
  builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

and in my appsettings.json I got all needed info such as clientId, tenantId, etc.

and all of this works fine.

But I wanted to also use ASP.NET Core Identity. As I don't want anyone in my organization to be able to login to the system. I only want certain people that I add through the system and have permission to access the system.

for this one I created a manage users page to add users to the system by searching AD and create them as users in the system and I gave them roles such as Admin.

This didn't work at first because Identity doesn't seam to work with external login. So to fix this I added a Scaffolded Item for login and logout.

And everything works fine.

Once user loges in through Ad I check on the system if this user exists or not, if yes I sign them in using SignInManager and then redirect them to the main page else they hit No Access page. This is my code

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CheckSignIn()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);

                if (user != null)
                {

                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);

                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
                }
                else
                {
                    await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("NoAccess", "ManageAccess");
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("NoAccess", "ManageAccess");
        }
```

Now the Issue is that After giving the user for example Admin role, when I add authentication header to my controller for example. It doesn't work and user is redirect to access denied page even though they have admin role.

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

How Can I fix this, The system doesn't Identify the user, I tried to check if user is signed in by using this code `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(user)`, but it doesn't work. The user is not signed in. It returns false.

So the user is never signed in and the system therefore doesn't recognize if he has the admin role that's why it redirect him to access denied page.

Any help on how to achieve this!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [claims transformation to add claims to existing identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation).

One more thing, please check theb order of the Authentication and Authorization in the pipeline. `Authentication` should be placed before `Authorization`.